# 'No such file or directory' when connecting to MySQL Server in Google App Engine in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, pdo, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to my Google Cloud SQL instance with PHP (I am using PDO). When running my PHP file (from in the Google Cloud terminal), I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /home/bob_brown_the_dev/index.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /home/bob_brown_the_dev/index.php(17): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=ma...', 'root', '', NULL)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/bob_brown_the_dev/index.php on line 17
```

This is what my PHP file looks like:

```php
<?php

$username = 'root';
$password = getenv("MYSQL_PASS");
$dbName = 'main';
$connectionName = getenv("INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME");
$socketDir = getenv('DB_SOCKET_DIR') ?: '/cloudsql';

$dsn = sprintf(
    'mysql:dbname=%s;unix_socket=%s/%s',
    $dbName,
    $socketDir,
    $connectionName
);

// Connect to the database.
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $conn_config);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

And this is what my app.yaml file looks like:

```yaml
runtime: php73

entrypoint:
  serve index.php

env_variables:
  APP_DEBUG: true
  LOG_CHANNEL: stderr
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: "<instance-id>:us-west2:<name>"
  DB_SOCKET_DIR: "/cloudsql/<instance-id>:us-west2:<name>"
  MYSQL_PASS: <password>
  DB_CONNECTION: mysql

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "<instance-id>:us-west2:<name>"
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:**

It appears there was a problem when I fetched the environmental variables. Once I fixed that problem, the error changed to:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Not a directory in /home/bob_brown_the_dev/index.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /home/bob_brown_the_dev/index.php(17): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', '...', '...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/bob_brown_the_dev/index.php on line 17
```

This is what the DSN looks like when I return it:

```
mysql:dbname=main;unix_socket=/cloudsql/<name>:us-west2:<other name>/<name>:us-west2:<other name>
```

Comment: Just wondering, did you care to display the actual DSN used? I mean, you are doing a lof os tuff from constructing yaml to getting env variables, all to get a DSN, but for some reason never checking the actual result, whether it looks good or not

Comment: @Your Common Sense Yep, I've done that. I just don't know if what it returned is in the correct format or not. I added what it returns to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your app in Cloud Shell, then you'll need to start the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy to mimic what App Engine does for you.

Start the proxy like this:

```
$ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<project-id>:us-west2:<instance-name> -dir /cloudsql
```

Note if `/cloudsql` doesn't exist, you'll have to manually create it.

Comment: Okay I will try the auth proxy. I think I need to manually create `/cloudsql`. Do I leave it as an empty directory?

Comment: Yep. Create the directory and leave it as empty. With the `-dir` flag you can specify any directory you like, however on App Engine (and Cloud Run and Functions), the service uses `/cloudsql` so for parity it's nice to use the same.

Comment: When I run that command, I receive this error: `listen unix /cloudsql/<instance-id>:us-west2:<instance-name>: bind: no such file or directory`

Comment: @Bob Brown Did you try with a modified answer by enocom?